# C# class to Json e6 class

Tags: c#, json, typescript, ecmascript-6, generate

I understand there is a plethora of tools out there to convert from json class / object to a C# class. Is there a way to do it the other way around? Get a C# class .. paste it in and generate a json object or typescript class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs two steps to do that:

1. Convert your C# class to JSON using [`C#TOJSON`](http://csharp2json.io/)
2. Convert your JSON to Interface using **[`JSON2TS`](http://json2ts.com/)**

Comment: That's crazy , why do you think it's not valid

Comment: Dude since you are accessing from Japan 

Comment: Yes that's why there is an edit option , there are N number of answers which had only links. Do you expect me to attach the tool within the answer? That does not make any sense

Comment: I've removed my comments because I can't be bothered anymore, but I stand by my point that when these links become invalid, your answer becomes invalid.

Comment: Yes I do accept that fact, but downvoting answer for that is absolutely not accepted. In fact I am trying to help someone .

Comment: It would be good like you removed the comments if you can remove downvote

Comment: @suliman again link is the answer for this question. No way to extract content from there

Comment: Everyone is going crazy without even understanding or going through the question, you guys should explain how this answer could be improved if you are doing a review.

Comment: Thanks dude! atleast you understood that it helps :)

Comment: Answer is good enough at this point. I also understand both points of the discussion: on the one hand, it's true, if one or both links become invalid, the answer pretty much becomes invalid, but, on the other hand, the lack of a known IDE implementation of said issue (vs code or vs for example), leaves us with the only valid answer at hand which is actually to point to an existing site that provides said service.